# How to run Python script with parameters and returned values in scripted Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm very new to writing Jenkinsfile. I have 2 Python scripts which takes in an input and also returns value that I would like to execute in a Jenkins pipeline.

How should I make the Python script calls in the Jenkinsfile?

Here's the expected flow of the Pipeline written in a scripted Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    stage('Code Test Run') {
        //Test runs and completes and produce result in XML format.
    }
    stage('Parse XML') {
        //**Python script 1 takes the XML from file directory as input and parse the XML. Returns parsed XML.**
    }
    stage('Publish to website') {
        //**Python script 2 takes returned value from Python script 2 as input and makes API call. Returns status of API call.**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Python installed in your Jenkins Agent, you can simply use the `shell` step to execute `Python` and use the `returnStdout` flag to capture the execution output.

```
// Git committer email
OUTPUT = sh (
    script: "python3 some.py $SOME_ARG",
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

Comment: How do I write the command in a sh block? Thanks for your answer

Comment: @ronmakh I have given you an example in my answer.

Comment: Noted on that, thanks. I am writing in a sh block, as is:-

sh """
PYTHON CODE TO BE WRITTEN

"""

I tried 'script_output= python xml_parser.py testoutput.xml' but it didn't work

Comment: @ronmakh what errors do you see?